# Request body is encrypted

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to receive a JSON request from a mobile app into my site, using the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{platform:minlength(2)}/{leagueID:int}/leagueteams")]
public IActionResult ExportLeagueTeams([FromRoute] string platform, 
[FromRoute] int leagueID)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.logFile))
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.logFile, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLineAsync("***").Wait();
                writer.WriteLineAsync("Testing this log").Wait();
                writer.WriteLineAsync("Platform: " + platform).Wait();
                writer.WriteLineAsync("LeagueID: " + leagueID).Wait();
                writer.WriteLineAsync("HEADERS:").Wait();

                // Get the headers
                foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
                {
                    writer.WriteLineAsync(header.Key + ": " + header.Value).Wait();
                }

                writer.WriteLineAsync("BODY (raw):").Wait();

                // get the Body of the request
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
                {
                    var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    writer.WriteLineAsync(body).Wait();
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

This will get the request from my mobile app I'm trying to use, however, the request body looks.... odd. It's definitely either encrypted or binary. I can't copy and paste from my log because the body is only being copied and pasted as

> BODY:
>   �

The request headers are as follows:

```
HEADERS:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json
Host: mywebsite.azurewebsites.net
Max-Forwards: 10
User-Agent: ProtoHttp 1.3/DS 15.1.2.2.0 (Android)
Content-Length: 1811
X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /api/Madden/ps4/6909313/leagueteams
CLIENT-IP: 73.13.26.24:47529
X-ARR-LOG-ID: 425fb24e-aa9f-4422-9dd2-b3b407240453
DISGUISED-HOST: mywebsite.azurewebsites.net
X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: mysebsite
WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: mywebsite.azurewebsites.net
X-Original-URL: /api/Madden/ps4/6909313/leagueteams
X-Forwarded-For: 73.13.26.24:47529
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4|CN=*.azurewebsites.net
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: 8c86c695-eec2-4328-a7ed-b2c2f10b9603
X-Original-For: 127.0.0.1:56457
X-Original-Proto: http
```

How can I decode/decrypt the request body?

Comment: Do you have access to the code that sends the request?

Comment: That ends or sends?

Comment: That sends the Http request. Sorry typo

Comment: Do you have access to the mobile app code, or is it foreign to you?

Comment: No that's all proprietary, sadly.

Comment: Maybe they use another character encoding. Can you try to use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`

Comment: Are you sure the data is not just compressed, and the request-related code/classes you use just fail/refuse to decompress it? Note that the request header explicitly states that the content is GZip compressed.

Comment: Your code is weird. Normally, the body was already read when you get to the Action so you cannot re-read it using `Request.Body`. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to accept a json object and load it into my database. Am I not supposed to be handling the request in my controller?

Comment: @elgonzo I saw that! Although when I did a test that header was also there so I kinda ignored it. How can I decompress that then?

Comment: My comment is only speculation, of course. I would expect the Request-related classes to handle decompression transparently, but i don't really have much experience with ASP.NET. To do a quick check if the data is indeed still being gzip-compressed  -- this is not meant to be a suggestion of how to improve/change your production code!!! --, you might use [GZipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) and see whether it can successfully decompress the data. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If the data was not GZip-compressed anymore (i.e., GZipStream didn't help), i would suggest to dump the data your server gets into some (temp) file and then inspect it with some hex editor in an attempt to identify what that data actually might be...

Comment: @IanKemp you rock, sir. Thanks for the push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it! The file was coming over compressed.

Using [Anemonis.AspNetCore.RequestDecompression](https://github.com/alexanderkozlenko/aspnetcore-request-decompression), I was able to add the following to my `Startup.cs` code

`ConfigureServices` code

```
/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">Services to include</param>
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // Add Decompression options
    var decompressOptions = new RequestDecompressionOptions();
    decompressOptions.UseDefaults();
    decompressOptions.AddProvider<GzipDecompressionProvider>();
    decompressOptions.SkipUnsupportedEncodings = false;
    services.AddRequestDecompression(decompressOptions);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySiteUsers");
    var mailingListConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MailingList");
    services.AddDbContext<MySiteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddDbContext<MySiteMailingListContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(mailingListConnection));
}
```

`Configure` Code

```
/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param>
/// <param name="env"></param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // This is where you use the Request Decompression
    app.UseRequestDecompression();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
}
```

Big thanks to @IanKemp for the push in the right direction